# How can I get the total number for an object's properties in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using an object to store state and the object looks like this:

```
{
  "CPC": 0,
  "NDP": 0,
  "LPC": 0,
  "GPC": 1,
  "PPC": 2
}
```

Where all the key values are an enumerator of a generic type `<T>`.

Suppose I can call this object, as such:

```js
console.log(this.optionVotes()); 
// Produces:
{  "CPC": 0,   "NDP": 0,   "LPC": 0,   "GPC": 1,   "PPC": 2 }
```

What is the best way I can get the of value 3 from this?

Comment: Do u mean u want to some each value inside json keys?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati do you mean "sum" each value?

Comment: @Akiva yes, Please check the answers

Comment: JSON means JavaScript object notation. When dealing with JSON strings, you can get native JavaScript objects out of them via `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Unfortunately the small detail was missed in both the answers. its `const data : T` where `T` is a string enumerator. I can't get my code to compile because its complaining about about types.

Comment: @Akiva Can you please update your question with an example for the string enumerator? What error message do you see?

Comment: It may be the case that you have to type for `<T extends object>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const data = {  "CPC": 0,   "NDP": 0,   "LPC": 0,   "GPC": 1,   "PPC": 2 };
const result = Object
  .keys(data)
  .reduce((a, key) => a + data[key], 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I recommend also using the `index`, `array` arguments of the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. That makes refactoring it easier if you want to define it as an external function.

Answer (score 2):

`Objec.value(obj)` will return an array of values inside keys and reduce does the rest of adding each value in var `c` counter inside reduce's callback.

```js
var foo =  {  "CPC": 0,   "NDP": 0,   "LPC": 0,   "GPC": 1,   "PPC": 2 } 
console.log(Object.values(foo).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0))
```

Comment: This does not work, if foo is a generic type.

Comment: @Akiva Can you please give an example or test case?